# How to make common template with dynamic binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, controltemplate

I have created different controls in WPF with their respective control templates in which styling is almost similar but binding is different, as given below removing extra clutter. I am looking for a  way to make a common `ControlTemplate` with some way to make the binding dynamic.

`ControlTemplate` for MasterRuleLayout control

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MasterRuleLayout}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image  
            Style="{StaticResource MasterLayoutImageStyle}"
            DataContext="{Binding CommonAggregate.SelectedRule}">
        </Image>
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding CommonAggregate.SelectedRule.Name}">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CommonAggregate.SelectedRule.Parent}" 
                                     Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

`ControlTemplate` for MasterEntityLayout control

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MasterEntityLayout}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image  
            Style="{StaticResource MasterLayoutImageStyle}"
            DataContext="{Binding CommonAggregate.SelectedEntityItem}">
        </Image>
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding CommonAggregate.SelectedEntityItem.Name}">               
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: What is supposed to be dynamic and in what way?

Comment: The binding that is taking place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings need dependency properties to form the "glue" between the properties in your template bindings and the properties in the view models that you're binding to. That means your options are 1) use TemplateBinding to bind via existing properties in the templated parent, 2) create a custom control with any additional properties that are missing, or 3) use attached properties:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:AttachedProps.Name), Mode=OneWay,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Control Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
    local:AttachedProps.Name="{Binding MyViewModelName, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And then you would create the attached property itself like so:

```
public static class AttachedProps
{
    #region Name

    public static string GetName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(NameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(NameProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Name", typeof(string),
        typeof(AttachedProps), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

    #endregion Name
}
```

Comment: One question if i am binding to dependency property of the control, how to keep the values in sync? Because there is a possibility that source value may change.

Comment: That's fine, it'll update automatically whenever the `MyViewModelName` property updates.